# Product formula for unit integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am trying to understand the proof given in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/ostrowskinumbfield.pdf of the product formula:
[image]
In the proof, it says the following: "The formula is clear when $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$, since every term in the product is 1".

Is this correct? I understand why the terms corresponding to the non-archimedean valuations are 1, but I am not sure why the archimedean ones must be 1.

If $\tau : K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an embedding, why $|\tau(\alpha)|=1$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The individual archimedean factors need not be $1$, but their product is since units have norm $\pm 1$.

Comment: The error in that argument has been fixed now.